# Return the column of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given a cell, I'm looking for a function and formula solution which returns its column. For instance,

- Given Cell `G3`, I expect the formula to return Column `G:G` (rather than the string `G:G` and the column number `7`)
- Given Cell `H8`, I expect the formula to return Column `H:H` (rather than the string `H:H` and the column number `8`)

Such a solution does not seem to exist in Excel today. Could anyone help?

PS: Given a Cell `B3`, I'm looking for a formula to return the result like what is displayed in Column I.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to then pass that reference to some function, e.g. `INDEX`? If so, you should clarify that in your question. I would hope that you are not actually wishing to return the string "G:G" and then pass that to, for example, `INDIRECT`, which is inefficient and almost always avoidable.

Comment: I modified a little bit the OP.

Comment: Can you give a practical example? I'm struggling to think of a case where this might actually be necessary.

Comment: can you just use `=Column`?

Comment: ?? You want to return 1048576 cells??

Comment: @JosWoolley See the image I added.

Comment: I have. It appears that you want to return all 1048576 cells within that column. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: If you say so... it is also what `=I:I` returns.

Comment: Well, `=INDEX(1:1048576,,COLUMN(B3))`, which obviously has to be placed in row 1, but it's never something I would even consider, creating over 17 billion dependencies and returning more than a million cells.

Comment: Is this an example of a XY-problem?

Comment: @TomNavidi, No, i have concrete examples where the solution of this question will be useful. But even an XY-problem would be a valid question for SO.

Comment: @JosWoolley Indeed, `=INDEX(1:1048576,,COLUMN(B3))` returns what I want, but it is not ideal.

Comment: Well, we could reduce 1:1048576 if you can place an upper bound on the columns which may be referenced.

Comment: Will you allow a `UDF` (`VBA`)?

Comment: @VBasic2008, i'm looking for a pure Excel function & formula solution.

Comment: Yeah, but you could test it and inform us if that's what you need. Then someone could possibly easier find an excel formula solution or 'unveil' the 'XY'.

Comment: @VBasic2008 `=INDEX(1:1048576,,COLUMN(B3))` returns what i want, but the problem is it uses too many rows (I'm afraid it will be slow), and also what if Excel will have more than 1048576 rows one day?

Comment: You want to type "Cell B3" into cell F1 and the formula to make column I equal to column B?

Comment: @Dave, I want to type `B3` into a formula.

Comment: Re "it uses too many rows", you said you wanted to return the whole column.

Comment: @JosWoolley well, what is more worrying is "what if Excel will have more than 1048576 one day".

Comment: I'm confused. Your example shows "Cell B3" as the input. The content of cell B3 is "C". The output shows the contents of column B.

Comment: Re "what if Excel will have more than 1048576 one day", if you have a workbook in which you'd want to return more than a million rows in a single formula then I'd consider rethinking your set-up. It's not my fault that if you enter `A:XFD` as the range then Excel changes it to `1:1048576`. You could overcome this with `INDIRECT`, but then the volatility in your workbook with all those cells being referenced would be disastrous.

Comment: Well, `=A:A` returns also one million rows, but we are not worried about its efficiency and consistency (when Excel will have more rows one day); returning one million rows is not necessarily bad. What seems me less perfect in `=INDEX(1:1048576,,COLUMN(B3))` is it uses the constant number `1048576`.

Comment: @JosWoolley So far, regardless of several downvotes of the question, the good news is that it is indeed feasible in Excel, and `=INDEX(1:1048576,,COLUMN(B3))` and a solution with `INDIRECT` are two potential solutions, though they are not perfect.

Comment: If you want a dynamic last row you can use something like `=countblank(a:a) + counta(a:a)`

Comment: I get a #SPILL error if I copy exactly what you have there. Would you be better using an OFFSET()?

Comment: @Dave you need to put that in the first row.

Comment: You could replace the 1:1048576 with OFFSET(1:1,0,0,ROWS(A:A)) to allow for Excel one day getting bigger. Not sure how optimised that would be though

Comment: @Dave I would think the downside of the volatility would outweigh the benefits in that case.

Comment: Wait, if you're sure you'll never be referencing column XFD, you can use `=INDEX(A:XFC,,COLUMN(B3))`. No volatility.

Comment: @JosWoolley either `XFC` or `XFD` is constant to refer to the limit of columns of Excel, it is not perfect.

Comment: Ok, well if you're now saying that you might one day have a worksheet which needs to be filled as far as column XFD then I give up!

Comment: @JosWoolley thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about `=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:D,,COLUMN(B3)),"","")` which will return blank if blank and 0 if value 0 in the referenced column.

I also only referenced the first 4 columns, since your search/example data starts from column 5. Excel would then always reference up untill the last row regardless the version.

Comment: Re "Excel would then always reference up until the last row regardless the version", see the OP's replies to my comments - they are apparently also wanting to reference up to the last column, regardless of version.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I mentioned it. Like you already stated, if you reference all columns in the sheet Excel will translate that to all rows, resulting in a conflict with old Excel versions and possibly missing rows for future versions.